# insert selected value from drop down by razor mvc

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

> hi, I had aproject and one of my task as to insert selected value from
>   drop down to DB field by razor mvc. I did my code but no values inserted ,Also the DDL have items from DB well . my project with razor mvc4.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();

        foreach (var t in data)
        {

            s.Text = t.Name;
            s.Value = t.Cat_ID.ToString();
            items.Add(s);
        }
        ViewBag.Parent = items;

        return View();
    }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];

            var fileSavePath = "";
            var fileName = "";


            fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName);

            uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            category.Path = "~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName;
        }

        var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in data)
        {
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = t.Name;
            s.Value = t.Cat_ID.ToString();
            items.Add(s);
            if (s.Selected)
            { category.Parent_ID = int.Parse(s.Value); }
        }

        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Your code should be something like this. I am assuming that you have model with certain structure. If belo code does not give you a clue then please. Tell how your view and model is and what is your requirement.

Hope this helps.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Category category, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];

        var fileSavePath = "";
        var fileName = "";


        fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
        fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName);

        uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        category.Path = "~/App_Data/Uploads/" + fileName;
    }

    var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();

    //I assume that you need to find the category from db.Caegories which user has selected on the UI and submited the form.
    //I assume the parameter category is the one which you want to find from DB.
    //category is your model has Parent_Id property which is bound to UI control (ie. dropdown) 
    var categoryToSave = (from c in data
                            where c.Cat_ID == category.Parent_ID
                            select c).firstOrDefault();
    if(categoryToSave!=null)
    {
//I believe here you want to save this category to some other table. 
//Now you have got the category tht user has selected on UI. 
//Write the further logic here.....

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Regards, Mahesh

Comment: I think you will need to use model. bind that model to your view. When yo submit that view you will get user selected values back in the model.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the fresh selectListItem s here in the same loop. You will get seleced == true for any of the item.

May be item, that user has selected on UI (before post) exist in category param if it is your model that is bound to desired dropdown.

I suspect it is a logical error.

Regards, Mahesh

Comment: Tell us your requirement and how your model is structured.